# Trying to make my app play stories like Snapchat Stories

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm working on creating a stories feature in my app like Snapchat. I have an array that I fill with videos and pictures from firebase and also some basic information about the story. The problem I am having is going through the array the way snapchat does. I am able to load the array content onto my ViewController but I can't tap through it the way I want to. Like after the first story plays I want the second story in the array to automatically play after and so on with the next story. But I also want the user to be able to to tap the right side of the view to skip to the next story or tap the left side to go to the previous story. Or if it is the first story in the array I want it to play from the beginning. But apparently the way my code is setup is just wrong and not doing what I need to do. Here is my code.
First I get the data from Firebase and fill the array by calling the function GetStories in ViewDidAppear.

```
func GetTheStories() {
    print("the EventID is \(self.EventID)")
    self.ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference(fromURL: "https://pondu-7db05.firebaseio.com/")

    let dataRef = self.ref.child("Stories")

    dataRef.observe(.value, with: { snapshot in

        if ( snapshot.value is NSNull ) {
            print("not found")

        } else {

            for Stories in (snapshot.children) {

                let snap = Stories as! FIRDataSnapshot //each child is a snapshot
                let dictionary = snap.value as? [String: AnyObject] // the value is a dict

                if self.EventID == dictionary?["EventID"] as! String! {

                    self.StoryURL = dictionary?["Story Link"] as? String!
                    self.UserID = dictionary?["UserID"] as? String!

                    self.fileArray.append(self.StoryURL)

                }


            }
            print("the array has this info in it \(self.fileArray) , okay cool")
            self.getFileType(self.fileArray[0])

        }

    })

 }
```

Then I call the Function GetFileType to determine if the file is an image or a video (this code is a little messed up but thats for another question).

```
func getFileType(_ thefile:String){

    var indexOfUrl:[Character] = []

    for i in thefile.characters {
        //print(i)

        indexOfUrl.append(i)
    }

    let letterIndex = indexOfUrl.count - 1
    print("index \(letterIndex)")


    let chac1 = indexOfUrl[letterIndex]
    let chac2 = indexOfUrl[letterIndex - 1]
    let chac3 = indexOfUrl[letterIndex - 2]

    print("chac3 \(chac3)")

    let fileType = "\(chac3)\(chac2)\(chac1)"

    print("file type \(chac3)\(chac2)\(chac1)")



    if (fileType == videoTypes[0]) || (fileType == videoTypes[1]) || (fileType == videoTypes[2]) || (fileType == videoTypes[3]) || (fileType == videoTypes[4]) {

        self.isVideo(thefile)
        print("file type \(fileType)")
        print(thefile)




    }else{
    print("its a picture")

        self.isImage(thefile)
       // print("file type \(fileType)")
       // print(thefile)

    }


}
```

After all of that I allow the user to tap through the array using this code below. Now this is the main problem I want to solve. I already know that I am doing something wrong here but I guess I just don't know enough about programing to figure out a better solution.

```
@IBAction func Forward(_ sender: UIButton) {


    getFileType(fileArray[+1])
}

@IBAction func Backward(_ sender: UIButton) {

    let max = UInt32(fileArray.count)

    let ran = Int(arc4random_uniform(max))

    getFileType(fileArray[ran])

    self.getFileType(self.fileArray[0])

}
```

And I call this function to make the player go to the next story after one is finish playing.

```
func playerPlaybackDidEnd(_ player: Player) {
    print("play back")
    getFileType(fileArray[+1])
}
```

Comment: Hey did you ever figure out how to create this?  I have found nothing online about creating a "stories" system and I am about to create one using swift and firebase.  Let me know and we can work together on this!

Comment: @WayneFilkins Still nothing. But my app has multiple parts to it so I just started working on something else and decided to save this for later :/  . But I wouldn't mind working with you on this

Comment: How did you do it ? I am planning to do this but i have found nothing on the internet. @WayneFilkins

Answer (score 0):

Why do you do the +1 in the array? Why not have a global variable that stores the current video being shown and then increment that:

```
guard globalVar + 1 < fileArray.count else {
    //finish watching videos here
    return
}
globalVar += 1
getFileType(fileArray[globalVar])
```

or if the user presses back, and wants to go to a previous video:

```
guard globalVar - 1 > 0 else {
    getFileType(fileArray[0])
    return
}
globalVar -= 1
getFileType(fileArray[globalVar])
```